# tell MS Access VBA function to wait until subform finished calculation

Tags: ms-access, vba, wait, subform

I have a subform `sfrmMySubForm` including an unbound field called `CountRows` in the footer, which is set to `=Count(*)`. The subform is displayed in table view. I dynamically change the filtering of `sfrmMySubForm` by VBA Code. This works fine.

After the filter has been updated, I like to change the height of the subform according to the number of rows shown now. I wrote a function to do that, using `Me!sfrmMySubForm!CountRows` to get the information. This works fine, if I trigger the function by button, but if I call it after the filter-update code, `Me!sfrmMySubForm!CountRows` returns `0` - apparently the function has been called, before the subform calculated the new value of `CountRows` (took me some hours to find out).

**My Question:**
How can I tell my function to wait until the subform finished it's calculations? **Or** is there another way to get the number of rows displayed in a subform after a filter update - another way, that doesn't lead into the same problem?

I already thought of just looping around until `Me!sfrmMySubForm!CountRows > 0` but this won't work if there is really no data to be displayed...

Comment: Since your form is based on a recordset (and a small number of records), you could just use a recordset clone, movelast and then put the recordcount into CountRows.
i.e. Set rsC = Me.RecordsetClone: rsC.MoveLast: CountRows = rsC.RecordCount: Set rsC = Nothing

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn 's suggestion works for me. For those who follow up:
I needed to reference Microsoft DAO Object Library (menu Tools - References) and state `Dim rsC As DAO.Recordset`. The syntax for the subform is `Me!sfrmMySubForm.Form.RecordsetClone` or (giving the subform control's name by variable) `Me(strHoldingSubformControlName).Form.RecordsetClone`.